# networking in java for client server communication

Tags: java, linux, networking

I need to make a troubleshooting tool in java

From the java code, I need to communicate with tethereal (linux commands) to help me generate a `.pkt` file. The `.pkt` file will contain all the contents of the communication that took place between the client and the server- i.e. all the packet communication between the client and  server.

how should I do that?

Comment: Why 'in Java'? Wireshark already exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org)? That is a cross-platform Network Packet Capturing application.

The idea is that it captures all packets (TCP and UDP) that passes one network device (eg: WiFi card) and you apply a filter on the port that your application uses, and eventually an IP address. Very useful tool.

Comment: You're welcome, now, you can mark this answer as correct by clicking the green tick under the score of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do it in java you can use http://jnetpcap.com/ which is a wrapper for libpcap which works similar to tethereal.